# Циклический prompt в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

При объявлении пременной:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Выберите цвет: красный, зеленый или синий");
```

нужно сделать так, чтобы когда человек выбирал цвет, допустим "красный", совершалось определенное действие, а если он пишет, допустим "черный", то снова всплывало окно выбора цвета, пока человек не выберет цвет из предложенных, или не нажмет "Отмена".

Сколько пытался не могу сделать этого. Дошел до такого вида, теперь не могу понять как сравнить переменную userChoice со значениями массива.

```
var userChoice = prompt("Выберите цвет: красный, зеленый или синий");
var choiсes = ["красный", "зеленый", "синий"];

while (userChoice != "красный"){
    var userChoice = prompt("Выберите цвет: красный, зеленый или синий");
};
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код ваших попыток (пусть и не рабочий).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проверяет на существование в массиве доступного выбора с введенным значением, если оно найдено то выходит из цикла

```
var userChoice
var question = 'Выберите цвет: красный, зеленый или синий';
var choises = ["красный", "зеленый", "синий"];

while (choises.indexOf(prompt(question)) === -1){
    userChoice = prompt("Выберите цвет: красный, зеленый или синий");
};
```

Ещё более короткая запись, но она не будет реагировать на кнопку отмена, и будет требовать все же ввести значение:

```
var userChoice
var question = 'Выберите цвет: красный, зеленый или синий';
var choises = ["красный", "зеленый", "синий"];

while (choises.indexOf(userChoice = prompt(question)) === -1);
```

С обработкой кнопки **отмена**

```
var userChoice
var question = 'Выберите цвет: красный, зеленый или синий';
var choises = ["красный", "зеленый", "синий"];

while ((userChoice = prompt(question)) && choises.indexOf(userChoice) === -1);
```

Comment: Тут лучше `do { ... } while` использовать. Одним `prompt` меньше будет.

Comment: @Embedder Не могу не согласиться, ещё больше укоротил)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, вы, кстати, не учли случай "_или не нажмет "Отмена"_".

Comment: Шикарно, спасибо)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, до кучи можно ещё и `toLowerCase()` применить.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev либо дотошно будем клацать либо нажмем отмена, добавил в функционал в последнем варианте

Comment: Вот тут `choises.indexOf()` пропустили аргумент

Comment: @DmitriySimushev дада, сразу заметил, уже поставил, на SO писать, это тебе не в IDE катать :) Спасибо

Answer (score -3):

что-то вроде

```
var correctColor = false;
while (!correctColor) {
    var choice = prompt("Выберите цвет: красный, зеленый или синий")
    switch(choice){
        case 'красный':
            //действия
            correctColor = true; 
            break;
        case 'зеленый':
            //действия 
            correctColor = true; 
            break;
        case 'синий':
            //действия 
            correctColor = true; 
            break;
        default:
            correctColor = false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: собственно оставьте комментарий что ли кто минусанул) желательно аргументировать)

Comment: Запросто. Представьте, что у вас 1000 вариантов. Все еще будете писать `case` для каждого из них?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev , справедливо. согласен. Однако в вопросе фигурировало всего 3 варианта. От этого и исходил, но а по сути, все верно, решение далеко не самое хорошее. Решение Василия лучше.

Comment: Вот за костыльность решения (пусть и правильного) мой минус и стоит. Это как подсказка читающим, что так лучше не делать.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev учту на будущее)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev , вопрос не по сабжу. табуляцию как проставлять в коде?

Comment: Я использую пробелы =) Более того, большинство стайл гайдов, из тех что я видел, рекомендуют именно пробелы а не табы.